# How can I compare two similar XML files in XMLUnit

Tags: xmlunit

I want to use [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to compare two similar XML files.

Basically every thing is same, `File1` is a copy of `File2` , but in `File2` I have changed the order of some elements in one node.

I am trying to run a test where it compares these files and returns a result of *similar* and not treat these files as *different*.

Answer (score 8):

I think this link can help you - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-cq121906.html#N10158

Basically, if your File1 is like -

```
<account>
 <id>3A-00</id>
 <name>acme</name>
</account>
```

And File2 is same, but only differs in order of `<name>` and `<id>` -

```
<account>
 <name>acme</name>
 <id>3A-00</id>
</account>
```

Then you can write a test like below which will compare these and return similar.

```
public void testIdenticalAndSimilar() throws Exception {
   String controlXML = "<account><id>3A-00</id><name>acme</name></account>";
   String testXML = "<account><name>acme</name><id>3A-00</id></account>"; 
   Diff diff = new Diff(controlXML, testXML);
   assertTrue(diff.similar());
   assertFalse(diff.identical());
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: When I use a String the comparison works fine. But when I use the file it doesn't. 

I declare InputSource object for each file and then create a Diff object with the two InputSource objects in it. When I use the similar command in this way it fails and says that the files are different. Is this a valid way of comparing?

Comment: How big is your XML file? Could you paste the content here?

Comment: How to handle if any tag is missing say for example, from controlXML id tag is missing  

String controlXML = "<account><name>acme</name></account>";
String testXML = "<account><name>acme</name><id>3A-00</id></account>";

if there are more than 3 child node then comparison showing wired result

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
    // Assuming file1 and file2 are not deeply nested XML files
    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc1 = docBuilder.parse(file1);
    Document doc2 = docBuilder.parse(file2);

    // SOLUTION 1: Are the files "similar"?
    Diff diff = new Diff(doc1, doc2);
    System.out.println("Similar (true/false): " + diff.similar());

    // SOLUTION 2: Should you want detailed differences (especially useful for deeply nested files)
    Diff diff = new Diff(doc1, doc2);
    diff.overrideElementQualifier(new RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier()); 
    DetailedDiff detailedDiff = new DetailedDiff(diff); 
    System.out.println("Detailed differences: " + detailedDiff.getAllDifferences().toString());
```

Hope that helps a bit. Read up on XMLUnit [here](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/userguide/html/index.html#Writing%20XML%20comparison%20tests).

Answer (score 0):

```
diff =
        DiffBuilder.compare(expected)
          .withTest(toBeVerified)
          .ignoreWhitespace()
          .checkForSimilar()
          .withNodeMatcher(new DefaultNodeMatcher(ElementSelectors.byNameAndText, ElementSelectors.byName))
          .build();
```